# Importing a Wordpress modal into an index.php file

Tags: wordpress, indexing, modal-dialog

I am currently working with a custom made theme.
The Home/Start Page is an index.php file inside the theme directory.
This page is not accessible through Wordpress.

Now I want to insert a Modal Popup, which I made with a plugin into this index.php page.
Plus, I want to open up a session, so that the Modal opens up only once.

I rarely work with Wordpress, so please excuse my incompetence on this topic.
Hopefully somebody here knows more than me.

Thanks
AL

Comment: I'm sorry could you clarify what you want to do and why.

Comment: generally index.php is used for blog, why you cant be access it

Comment: I try to express my question a bit more clearly. Usually I insert modals with the Wordpress own Edit function.I just copy the code and it works. Unfortunately the starting page, is not accessible in Wordpress. Thus, I can not edit it inside of wordpress. I have to download the whole public folder and open it up in my IDE. My question is: How can I insert a modal which was made with a wordpress plugin, inside a page on the same site, which is not accessible through wordpress directly.